# Would you use Blazor WebAssembly to create an online banking application?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

Would you use Blazor WebAssembly to create an online banking application?

Things to consider:

- It's not a steep learning curve (the existing team is proficient in
  .Net, C# and MVC).
- It was only released in May 2020 (we are not normally early adopters of new technologies).
- It does not support IE (we currently have less than 5% of users on IE)
- No JavaScript for developers to write (No JS errors, No JS cross browser issues and the team are not JS developers, they are C# developers).

I appreciate this could be subjective, but I would imagine many .Net houses are considering using this technology to produce robust web applications. I am also requesting an answer that backs up a simple yes or no response with sound technological reasoning, either reflecting on the typical considerations I've mentioned above or on others I've missed.

** **UPDATE** **

The team agreed that at this moment in time Blazor was a step too far and opted to create a Razor Pages Web Application instead. For internal applications it would be a fine choice though. Thanks for the great answers.

Comment: If those 5% of users who are using IE can no longer use your application, how many of that 5% are valued customers? How many of that 5% will bother to switch to another browser? These are the questions I would be asking myself. If you risk losing clients because you don't support their browser of choice, I would think the answer would be "No".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes to internal facing or limited audience facing apps.

To give some counter weight: it is the JavaScript world that has most suffered from churn and fragmentation, especially in the frameworks years. If you want to build a reasonable CRUD platform, you would for the moment choose React, Angular or Vue. Will they still be a viable technology in five years time? .NET on the other hand has always been very stable.

We actually did choose Blazor as our technology and I have not regretted the choice. We have been doing full-time Blazor for the past few months. The productivity is insane with just one language. I can debug an API callback with a frontend state issue in one start/stop session. Yes, it still needs more polishing, but it is actually quite usable for such an engineering feat in a v1! But we have a small team with full stack developers, if you have larger teams this may not be such an advantage. And we do like that you can shared the contracts between frontend and backend. There are all sorts of little scenarios now possible because you share so much code. We use FluentValidation for example in forms and re-use the validators client-side as server side. A big win.

Our total payload including runtime is 3mb right now, for a complete platform. The largest part is runtime (900kb) and system dll's, that will be cached. A high profile site like the Verge is around 2mb. Performance is not an issue for us since 5.0.

Also, Blazor has a very well thought out Component model that is well matched with anything out there on the market. We could not find that many holes in the architecture. Yes, there are holes, but so far they are pretty limited in scope to the very edge of frontend (element sizing/positioning, scroll stuff).

Answer (score 2):

As someone who works as a consultant in the banking sector, I’d say no, not now. I’ve kicked off a few projects recently and Blazor has been mooted as a potential option. In each case we have decided against it.

Banks are typically pretty conservative as businesses, this isn’t a good place to try out cutting / bleeding edge technologies.

Blazor has some interesting potential, but it is a complex stack. In my experience technologies of this complexity often suffer from being ‘leaky abstractions’, you state that no JS is required, but in practice it’s likely you will need to plug some pretty big gaps. As an example, Blazor doesn’t have canvas support.

It currently has some pretty big limitations, shipping a .NET runtime to the browser is very costly. This is probably viable for internal apps, but for consumer facing apps (with occasional use) it’s a non starter in my opinion.

Can you be certain that it will still be a viable technology in five years time? Will it be the next Flash, Silverlight or Java FX?

After working with web tech for about 15 years, I do very much agree with Brendan Eich when he said ‘always bet on JavaScript’

Sorry to sound so negative. I do think Blazor is a amazing concept, but like most new technologies it is yet to find its niche.

Comment: I could argue that Canvas support is not high on the list for a banking app :-)

Comment: It depends on the type of banking app - quite a few do have charts and visualisations.

Comment: You can use any JavaScript library quite easily, Steve Sanderson demo-ed integration of a chart library with 3.2.0 release. We integrated FB FlatPickr in just a day or two to get a full fledged datetime picker. Two-way communication is possible, but has room for improvement. Real-time charts are a different matter, but you can use Window.AnimationFrame as callback mechanism for more performance

Comment: I like that "will still be a viable technology in five years time" is a criteria!  Most JS frameworks seem to have the half-life of butterflies. But I get the point.. :)

Comment: Very true @Quango - although I would much rather support a web application from 10 years ago written in Knockout.js than one written in Flash. Yes, JS frameworks are frustratingly short-lived, however, the underlying platform is very much here to stay.

Comment: @ColinE Your comment about Brendan Eich is a bit Mandy-Rice-Davies ("he would say that, wouldn't he"). When JS was the only game in town it made sense, but with WebAssembly that's no longer true - there are 17 languages that compile to WASM already and more being developed. https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs  - Blazor is the missing link in Microsoft's web client solution.